# Error in conformance of protocol to a class : Redundant conformance of "AnyClass" to protocol Equatable

Tags: xcode, swift

I have migrated my app to xCode 7 from xcode 6. 
I am getting errors **{"Redundant conformance of "AnyClass" to protocol Equatable"}** in conformance of protocol. While I have not done any extra thing regarding that. Do I need to do anything extra for Xcode 7.